# OS X terminal starts from other device (got rooted?)

Tags: virus, rootkits, trojan, terminal

I've recently noticed that my terminal starts with something like "android... " even though I don't have any android device. Furthermore I noticed that my macbook only starts with "android..." when it's connected to the internet. If I turn my wireless off, then my macbook starts with "USER-macbook-air" like usually. See the following pictures:

WLAN on (rooted by android device?):

[image: terminal shows "android-d367b...:~USER$" when WLAN is on]

WLAN off (usually looked like this):

[image: terminal shows "USER-MacBook-Air:~USER$" when WLAN is off]

I'm afraid that my macbook got roote (trojan, rootkit, virus?). Does someone know about anything like this? Or does someone know why my terminal starts with "android" ... and whose android device is it?!

I would be very thankful for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Likely answer: your wireless AP is assigning your IP and hostname and getting confused.

Lots of confirmation with a little Googling:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal

https://superuser.com/questions/663765/unknown-system-name-showing-up-in-terminal

Comment: Yeah you are right! I just didn't know what to google (tried "mac got rooted" ...) and thus, I couldn't find anything relevant. Thanks for the fast reply, now I can calm down.

Comment: Google the symptoms, not the suspected conclusion :)